# What's the generating formula for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Can someone help me finding the generating formula for this sequence?

$$[1,1,3,5,5,7,9,9,11,13,13...]$$

Thanks!

Comment: Someone, maybe. Some website, surely: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C9%2C11%2C13%2C13&language=english&go=Search

Comment: The question could be improved.  What did you try?  Are you implying that every third term is distinct and otherwise terms appear as repeated pairs?  The phrase *generating function* has a meaning in connection with sequences and risks confusion with your *generating formula*.

Comment: The question is nice, but it should be stated in a more precise way. May I dare to edit it?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect. E.g. Would be: These are the roots of the polynomial $x^9/6720-(9 x^8)/1120+(207 x^7)/1120-(189 x^6)/80+(5877 x^5)/320-(14283 x^4)/160+(150329 x^3)/560-(133101 x^2)/280+(93241 x)/210-163$ be a suitable answer?

Comment: @ahulpke: I do not understand your objection. The elements of a monotonic sequence cannot be the roots of a polynomial; the OP is just asking for some nice closed-form expression for the $n$-th term of the given sequence.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio   How do we know from the question that the sequence is monotonic. (My ``answer'' was intended to prompt a better explanation what is supposed to be modeled.)

Comment: @ahulpke: I don't get it, doesn't $1,1,3,5,5,7,9,9,\ldots$ look as a weakly monotonic sequence with a clear pattern to you?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio    Yes, it looks monotonic, but without context it could continue 1,1,1,1,1,1,.. or any other way.

Comment: @ahulpke: you're right, but that is not a substantial objection. We also use a pragmatic principle for which, when we write $1,2,\color{red}{\ldots},n$, we mean that the dots represent all the integer number between $3$ and $n-1$. Here the pattern is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is the weakly increasing sequence $1,1,3,5,5,7,9,9,13,\ldots$ given by repeating twice every number of the form $4n+1$, just once every number of the form $4k+3$, and:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n,\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(x) &=& \sum_{k\geq 0}\left[(4k+1) x^{3k}+(4k+1)x^{3k+1}+(4k+3)x^{3k+2}\right]\\&=&(1+x+x^2)\sum_{k\geq 0}(4k+1)x^{3k}+2\sum_{k\geq 0}x^{3k+2}\\&=&(1+x+x^2)\cdot\frac{1+3x^3}{(1-x^3)^2}+2\cdot\frac{x^2}{1-x^3}\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{1+2x^2+x^3}{(1-x)^2(1+x+x^2)}}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*} $$
By partial fraction decomposition we may check that:

> $$ a_n = \frac{4n+1+\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}(n+1)\right)}{3}.\tag{3} $$

Comment: I doubt the OP is asking about a generating function.  See his/her Comment on the other answer.

Comment: @hardmath: the generating function gives an answer to the intended OP's question, too, please see my update.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an explicit form for the sequence, then it is of course correct to state that
$$a_n=\frac{4n+1+\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} \sin \left( \frac{2\pi}{3}(n+1)\right)}{3}$$ as done above.
But there is also another (much simpler) term for $a_n$ which pays tribute to the simplicity of the underlying pattern:
$$a_n=1+2 \cdot \lfloor \frac{2n-2}{3} \rfloor$$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function (i.e. the largest integer smaller than $x$).

Comment: Interesting, following Tintarn's approach, I ended with the following pattern :
$a_n = 2\biggl\lfloor{n\over 3}\biggr\rfloor + 2\biggl\lfloor{n+1\over 3}\biggr\rfloor + 1$

Answer (score 0):

See this link [the sequence generated by this](https://oeis.org/search?q=%5B1%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C9%2C11%2C13%2C13&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for: I'm looking for an $F(n)$ such that $F(1)=1,F(2)=1,F(3)=3,F(4)=5,F(5)=5,F(6)=7$... etc